# displaying marker data from an edf file in MatLab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, matlab-figure

I am trying to get the marker data from and edf file in matlabl. I have used edf read like the below.

```
[hdr,label] = edfread('Subject1.edf');
```

when I type in hdr in the command window I get the below

```
      ver: 0
  patientID: '1                                                                               '
   recordID: '1                                                                               '
  startdate: '11.07.16'
  starttime: '07.52.30'
      bytes: 9472
    records: 948
   duration: 1
         ns: 36
      label: {1x36 cell}
 transducer: {1x36 cell}
      units: {1x36 cell}
physicalMin: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
physicalMax: [1x36 double]
 digitalMin: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 digitalMax: [1x36 double]
  prefilter: {1x36 cell}
    samples: [1x36 double]
```

and then the marker is in the label so I type in

```
hdr.label
```

which gives me the below

```
>> hdr.label

ans = 

  Columns 1 through 13

    'COUNTER'    'INTERPOLATED'    'AF3'    'F7'    'F3'    'FC5'    'T7'    'P7'    'O1'    'O2'    'P8'    'T8'    'FC6'

  Columns 14 through 24

    'F4'    'F8'    'AF4'    'RAW_CQ'    'CQ_AF3'    'CQ_F7'    'CQ_F3'    'CQ_FC5'    'CQ_T7'    'CQ_P7'    'CQ_O1'

  Columns 25 through 34

    'CQ_O2'    'CQ_P8'    'CQ_T8'    'CQ_FC6'    'CQ_F4'    'CQ_F8'    'CQ_AF4'    'CQ_CMS'    'CQ_DRL'    'GYROX'

  Columns 35 through 36

    'GYROY'    'MARKER'
```

So my question is, how do I get the marker data? I typed in

```
>> hdr.label.marker
```

but i get an error saying

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label field isn't a struct, then you can't access using dot notation. You should access using "cell array" indexing:

```
hdr.label{end} % last element
```

the above returns the `'MARKER'` string.

Comment: how can I plot the marker data on the graph or access specific points of the marker data?